# Connecting robot to mobile application via a webserver and webosckets

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, rosbridge-suite, websocket

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm putting together a project which is a robot that moves around a space on a schedule. The basic idea is to be able to view information from the robot on a mobile application that's written in react native, while also being able to set when the robot starts etc.

The basic overall system will communicate like this ROS robot <-> websocket <-> webserver <-> websocket <-> mobile application.

The issue is I don't have any experience in anything other than the developing a ROS robot. I guess I'm just looking for guidance on how I should do this whole thing.

Has anyone had a project like this before?  I'm going to use rosbridge_suite for the ROS side websocket, but haven't a clue about the server stuff.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks for reading this far!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/366407/connecting-robot-to-mobile-application-via-a-webserver-and-webosckets/) by [TheMilkman92](https://answers.ros.org/users/60334/themilkman92/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2020-11-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I cannot say I have extensive experience with what you want to do, but I lab I work with uses a system that sounds kinda like what you want to do called [robofleet](https://github.com/ut-amrl/robofleet). The GitHub (linked before) is public and you can snoop around there, the documentation is ok and maybe you can try to use that first if you find it is easy to setup and then go from there.

Let me know what you think,
Cheers

---

Originally posted by [JackB](https://answers.ros.org/users/40162/jackb/) with karma: 977 on 2020-11-26

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [TheMilkman92](https://answers.ros.org/users/60334/themilkman92/) on 2020-11-26**:
That's an interesting project, looks pretty close to what I'm trying to do! Thanks for the help, I'll look more into it.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`rosjs` will be an option.
You can send topics to ROS from javascript via rosbridge_suite.

You can also find a tutorial at http://wiki.ros.org/ja/rosbridge/jaTutorials/Using%20Javascript%20to%20control%20ROS%20via%20rosjs.

---

Originally posted by [miura](https://answers.ros.org/users/59801/miura/) with karma: 1908 on 2020-11-26

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1